# CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE when setting kernel arg

Tags: c++, gpu, opencl

I'm making an attempt to break away from CUDA and learn OpenCL. I thought an n-body simulation might be a good place to start. I've been using the c++ wrapper, and following the tutorial provided [here](https://www.eriksmistad.no/using-the-cpp-bindings-for-opencl/) to get a basic idea of how things should work.

The program loads 2 source files, one for each kernel function. Each is compiled, and built into a separate kernel. On my first attempt, they were in the same kernel. This was an attempt to fix the issue by doing something different.

**nbs_forces.cl**:

```cpp
typedef struct body_t {
...
};

__kernel void execute(__global struct body_t* bodies, const float G, const int n){
    ...
}
```

**nbs_positions.cl**:

```cpp
typedef struct body_t {
...
};

__kernel void execute(__global struct body_t* bodies, const float dt, const int n){
...
}
```

The buffers are allocated as such:

```cpp
// create memory buffers
bGravity = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(float));
bBodies = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
            capacity * sizeof(body_t));
bTimestep = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(float));
bSize = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(int));
```

After the data is copied to the buffers, and it comes time to run the simulation, I set the kernel arguments as such:

```cpp
fKernel->setArg(0, *bBodies);
fKernel->setArg(1, *bGravity);
fKernel->setArg(2, *bSize);

pKernel->setArg(0, *bBodies);
pKernel->setArg(1, *bTimestep);
pKernel->setArg(2, *bSize);

cl::NDRange global(capacity);
cl::NDRange local(1);

for (int step = 0; step < steps; step++) {
    queue->enqueueNDRangeKernel(*fKernel, cl::NullRange, global, local);
    queue->enqueueNDRangeKernel(*pKernel, cl::NullRange, global, local);
}
```

But on execution of the second line of the simulation function (**setKernelArg(1, *bGravity)**), the program terminates with **CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE**. It seemed like it should be a trivial error to solve, but try as I might, I can't seem to find anything that would cause it.

I've tried passing different data types, including the types provided by opencl (cl_float, etc), but the problem remains. I'm sure I've just done something dumb, but I've been banging my head against the wall for the past few days to no avail.

In my attempt to keep this post short, if there's any critical code I neglected to include, everything can be found on the git repo [here](https://github.com/Techmo2/NBS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mismatch between your kernel's expected arguments:

```
__kernel void execute(__global struct body_t* bodies, const float G, const int n)
```

(a buffer containing an array of `struct body_t`, and 2 scalar values)

and what you actually pass to it:

```
bGravity = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(float));
bBodies = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
            capacity * sizeof(body_t));
…
bSize = new cl::Buffer(*context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(int));
…
fKernel->setArg(0, *bBodies);
fKernel->setArg(1, *bGravity);
fKernel->setArg(2, *bSize);
```

`G` and `n` should not be passed as buffers. Instead, the following should do the trick:

```
const float gravity = …;
const int32_t size = …;

fKernel->setArg(1, gravity);
fKernel->setArg(2, size);
```

Comment: Gave your answer a try, but unfortunately it seems to produce the same behavior. An interesting update though, if built with -O2, it produces a different error, clEnqueueWriteBuffer, which makes me think that the problem might be earlier in the pipeline.

Comment: Hmm, differences based on optimisation level suggest undefined behaviour in your code, so yes it does sound like perhaps the code you posted has little to do with your underlying issue.

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed something: the second and third kernel arguments aren't pointers, and so shouldn't be passed as buffers. Simply pass a (reference to) the local variable of the correct type.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer based on my rereading of your question.

Comment: That did the trick :). I was under the impression that everything needed to be wrapped in a buffer, but I guess that isn't the case. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Only `global` pointer arguments (and images) correspond to host-side buffers. Scalar arguments are passed directly as described in my answer, though I wouldn't rely on this for anything but built-in types. Passing structs by value doesn't work reliably in all implementations, and the standard doesn't directly say anything about this. You can also have kernel arguments with `local` pointer type, where the host side merely needs to set the size, you can't provide a value.

Comment: If you absolutely must use structs, use the "packed" attribute on them (or arrange them so the're packed without using the attribute). In C, the padding between struct elements is not defined by the standard, and can be different between device compiler and the host code compiler, so you need to be careful with it.

Comment: @mogu Using the `packed` attribute can have negative consequences as the compiler may need to emit code for unaligned access. But the point is a good one: you must ensure that the field offsets and alignment of structs shared between host and kernel match up. The alignment rules for OpenCL kernels are specified, so I have found the most practical approach to be to use `static_assert`ions with `offsetof` and `alignof` to verify that the host side struct matches the kernel rules.